# Opensips 2.4 can't make outbound call

Tags: sip, voip, opensips, debian-buster

I followed tutorial on https://www.powerpbx.org/content/opensips-v24-debian-v8-mariadb-apache-v1

With minor tweaks for "Debian Buster" I have installed all components, services starts with no error, I created few subscribers from opensipscp, under alias I added DID number pointing username of sip device, under routing added dr_gateway with type 1 and added ip address of DID provider trunk.

Inbound calls are fine.
Then I added IP's for my outbound trunks, set gateway type - 2
Added rules to include all outbound gateways for prefix starting 353
In dialplan I have added rule to translate from local format to E164, but it seem to not work

I can't get my head around how to succeed with outbound calls, I have spent whole weekend digging trough opensips documentation page and the book "Building Telephony Systems with OpenSIPS Second Edition" by Flavio-E.-Goncalves over and over again.

Here is debug output form opensips during call

```
DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: dpid is 10 partition is default
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_get_svalue: searching 15
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: input is 0899000000
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: Checking with dpid 10
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:translate: No matching rule for input 0899000000
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: could not translate 0899000000 with dpid 10
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: dpid is 10 partition is default
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_get_svalue: searching 15
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: input is 0899000000
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: Checking with dpid 10
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:translate: No matching rule for input 0899000000
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:dialplan:dp_translate_f: could not translate 0899000000 with dpid 10
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:registrar:parse_lookup_flags: final flags: 1
Dec 22 23:39:26 [892] DBG:registrar:lookup: '0899631338@example.ie' Not found in usrloc
```

Dialplan rule I am using is

```
MariaDB [opensips]> select * from dialplan;
+----+------+----+----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+
| id | dpid | pr | match_op | match_exp      | match_flags | subst_exp   | repl_exp  | timerec | disabled | attrs          |
+----+------+----+----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+
|  2 |   10 |  1 |        0 | ^089[0-9]{7}+$ |           0 | "^089(.+)$" | "35389\1" | NULL    |        0 | IE Lyca Mobile |
+----+------+----+----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+
```

my gateway list

```
MariaDB [opensips]> select * from dr_gateways;
+----+------+------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | gwid | type | address         | strip | pri_prefix | attrs | probe_mode | state | socket | description |
+----+------+------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | 1    |    1 | 1.1.1.1         |     0 |            |       |          0 |     0 |        | inbound     |
|  2 | 2    |    2 | 2.2.2.2         |     0 |            |       |          0 |     1 |        | gw 1        |
|  3 | 3    |    2 | 3.3.3.3         |     0 |            |       |          0 |     0 |        | gw 2        |
|  4 | 4    |    2 | 4.4.4.4         |     0 |            |       |          0 |     0 |        | gw 3        |
|  5 | 5    |    2 | 5.5.5.5         |     0 |            |       |          0 |     0 |        | gw 4        |
+----+------+------+-----------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Carriers

```
MariaDB [opensips]> select * from dr_carriers;
+----+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | carrierid | gwlist  | flags | state | attrs | description |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |           | 2,3,4,5 |     0 |     0 |       | Provide     |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

DR Rules

```
MariaDB [opensips]> select * from dr_rules;
+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
| ruleid | groupid | prefix | timerec | priority | routeid | gwlist  | attrs | description |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
|      1 | 0,1     | 353    |         |        1 |         | 2,3,4,5 |       | IE          |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

my opensips.cfg file

```
 #
# OpenSIPS residential configuration script
#     by OpenSIPS Solutions <team@opensips-solutions.com>
#
# This script was generated via "make menuconfig", from
#   the "Residential" scenario.
# You can enable / disable more features / functionalities by
#   re-generating the scenario with different options.#
#
# Please refer to the Core CookBook at:
#      http://www.opensips.org/Resources/DocsCookbooks
# for a explanation of possible statements, functions and parameters.
#


####### Global Parameters #########

log_level=3
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

children=4

/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
debug_mode=yes

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes

/* comment the next line to enable the auto discovery of local aliases
   based on reverse DNS on IPs */
auto_aliases=no


listen=udp:123.123.123.123:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME
listen=tcp:123.123.123.123:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME


####### Modules Section ########

#set module path
mpath="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensips/modules/"

#### SIGNALING module
loadmodule "signaling.so"

#### StateLess module
loadmodule "sl.so"

#### Transaction Module
loadmodule "tm.so"
modparam("tm", "fr_timeout", 5)
modparam("tm", "fr_inv_timeout", 30)
modparam("tm", "restart_fr_on_each_reply", 0)
modparam("tm", "onreply_avp_mode", 1)

#### Record Route Module
loadmodule "rr.so"
/* do not append from tag to the RR (no need for this script) */
modparam("rr", "append_fromtag", 0)

#### MAX ForWarD module
loadmodule "maxfwd.so"

#### SIP MSG OPerationS module
loadmodule "sipmsgops.so"

#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)

#### URI module
loadmodule "uri.so"
modparam("uri", "use_uri_table", 0)

#### MYSQL module
loadmodule "db_mysql.so"

#### HTTPD module
loadmodule "httpd.so"
modparam("httpd", "port", 8888)

#### USeR LOCation module
loadmodule "usrloc.so"
modparam("usrloc", "nat_bflag", "NAT")
modparam("usrloc", "db_mode",   2)
modparam("usrloc", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME


#### REGISTRAR module
loadmodule "registrar.so"
modparam("registrar", "tcp_persistent_flag", "TCP_PERSISTENT")
modparam("registrar", "received_avp", "$avp(received_nh)")/* uncomment the next line not to allow more than 10 contacts per AOR */
#modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 10)

#### ACCounting module
loadmodule "acc.so"
/* what special events should be accounted ? */
modparam("acc", "early_media", 0)
modparam("acc", "report_cancels", 0)
/* by default we do not adjust the direct of the sequential requests.
   if you enable this parameter, be sure the enable "append_fromtag"
   in "rr" module */
modparam("acc", "detect_direction", 0)
modparam("acc", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

#### AUTHentication modules
loadmodule "auth.so"
loadmodule "auth_db.so"
modparam("auth_db", "calculate_ha1", yes)
modparam("auth_db", "password_column", "password")
modparam("auth_db|uri", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("auth_db", "load_credentials", "")

#### ALIAS module
loadmodule "alias_db.so"
modparam("alias_db", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

#### DOMAIN module
loadmodule "domain.so"
modparam("domain", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("domain", "db_mode", 1)   # Use caching
modparam("auth_db|usrloc|uri", "use_domain", 1)

#### PRESENCE modules
loadmodule "xcap.so"
loadmodule "presence.so"
loadmodule "presence_xml.so"
modparam("xcap|presence", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("presence_xml", "force_active", 1)
modparam("presence", "fallback2db", 0)

#### DIALOG module
loadmodule "dialog.so"
modparam("dialog", "dlg_match_mode", 1)
modparam("dialog", "default_timeout", 21600)  # 6 hours timeout
modparam("dialog", "db_mode", 2)
modparam("dialog", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

####  NAT modules
loadmodule "nathelper.so"
modparam("nathelper", "natping_interval", 10)
modparam("nathelper", "ping_nated_only", 1)
modparam("nathelper", "sipping_bflag", "SIP_PING_FLAG")
modparam("nathelper", "sipping_from", "sip:pinger@127.0.0.1") #CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("nathelper", "received_avp", "$avp(received_nh)")

loadmodule "rtpengine.so"
modparam("rtpengine", "rtpengine_sock", "udp:localhost:2223") # CUSTOMIZE ME

####  DIALPLAN module
loadmodule "dialplan.so"
modparam("dialplan", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

####  DYNAMIC ROUTING module
loadmodule "drouting.so"
modparam("drouting", "db_url",
        "mysql://opensips:secret@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

####  MI_HTTP module
loadmodule "mi_http.so"
loadmodule "mi_json.so"
loadmodule "proto_udp.so"
loadmodule "proto_tcp.so"
####### Routing Logic ########

# main request routing logic

route{

        # initial NAT handling; detect if the request comes from behind a NAT
        # and apply contact fixing
        force_rport();
        if (nat_uac_test("23")) {
                if (is_method("REGISTER")) {
                        fix_nated_register();
                        setbflag(NAT);
                } else {
                        fix_nated_contact();
                        setflag(NAT);
                }
        }

        if (!mf_process_maxfwd_header("10")) {
                send_reply("483","Too Many Hops");
                exit;
        }

        if (has_totag()) {

                # handle hop-by-hop ACK (no routing required)
                if ( is_method("ACK") && t_check_trans() ) {
                        t_relay();
                        exit;
                }

                # sequential request within a dialog should
                # take the path determined by record-routing
                if ( !loose_route() ) {
                        if (is_method("SUBSCRIBE") && is_myself("$rd")) {
                                # in-dialog subscribe requests
                                route(handle_presence);
                                exit;
                        }
                        # we do record-routing for all our traffic, so we should not
                        # receive any sequential requests without Route hdr.
                        send_reply("404","Not here");
                        exit;
                }

                # validate the sequential request against dialog
                if ( $DLG_status!=NULL && !validate_dialog() ) {
                        xlog("In-Dialog $rm from $si (callid=$ci) is not valid according to dialog\n");
                        ## exit;
                }

                if (is_method("BYE")) {
                        # do accounting even if the transaction fails
                        do_accounting("db","failed");

                }


                if (check_route_param("nat=yes"))
                        setflag(NAT);
                # route it out to whatever destination was set by loose_route()
                # in $du (destination URI).
                route(relay);
                exit;
        }

        # CANCEL processing
        if (is_method("CANCEL")) {
                if (t_check_trans())
                        t_relay();
                exit;
        }

        # absorb retransmissions, but do not create transaction
        t_check_trans();

        if ( !(is_method("REGISTER")  || is_from_gw() ) ) {

                if (is_from_local()) {
                        # authenticate if from local subscriber
                        # authenticate all initial non-REGISTER request that pretend to be
                        # generated by local subscriber (domain from FROM URI is local)
                        if (!proxy_authorize("", "subscriber")) {
                                proxy_challenge("", "0");
                                exit;
                        }
                        if (!db_check_from()) {
                                send_reply("403","Forbidden auth ID");
                                exit;
                        }

                        consume_credentials();
                        # caller authenticated

                } else {
                        # if caller is not local, then called number must be local

                        if (!is_uri_host_local()) {
                                send_reply("403","Relay Forbidden");
                                exit;
                        }
                }

        }

        # preloaded route checking
        if (loose_route()) {
                xlog("L_ERR",
                        "Attempt to route with preloaded Route's [$fu/$tu/$ru/$ci]");
                if (!is_method("ACK"))
                        send_reply("403","Preload Route denied");
                exit;
        }

        # record routing
        if (!is_method("REGISTER|MESSAGE"))
                record_route();

        # account only INVITEs
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {

                # create dialog with timeout
                if ( !create_dialog("B") ) {
                        send_reply("500","Internal Server Error");
                        exit;
                }

                do_accounting("db");

        }


        if (!is_uri_host_local()) {
                append_hf("P-hint: outbound\r\n");

                route(relay);
        }

        # requests for my domain

        if( is_method("PUBLISH|SUBSCRIBE"))
                        route(handle_presence);

        if (is_method("REGISTER")) {
                # authenticate the REGISTER requests
                if (!www_authorize("", "subscriber")) {
                        www_challenge("", "0");
                        exit;
                }

                if (!db_check_to()) {
                        send_reply("403","Forbidden auth ID");
                        exit;
                }
                if ($proto == "tcp")
                        setflag(TCP_PERSISTENT);
                if (isflagset(NAT)) {
                        setbflag(SIP_PING_FLAG);
                }
                if (!save("location"))
                        sl_reply_error();

                exit;
        }

        if ($rU==NULL) {
                # request with no Username in RURI
                send_reply("484","Address Incomplete");
                exit;
        }


        # apply DB based aliases
        alias_db_lookup("dbaliases");


        **# apply transformations from dialplan table
        dp_translate("10","$rU/$rU");


        if (dp_translate("10","$rU/$rU") ) {

                if (!do_routing("0")) {
                        send_reply("500","No PSTN Route found");
                        exit;
                }

                route(relay);
                exit;
        }**


        # do lookup with method filtering
        if (!lookup("location","m")) {
                if (!db_does_uri_exist()) {
                        send_reply("420","Bad Extension");
                        exit;
                }

                # redirect to a different VM system
                $du = "sip:127.0.0.2:5060"; # CUSTOMIZE ME
                route(relay);

        }

        if (isbflagset(NAT)) setflag(NAT);

        # when routing via usrloc, log the missed calls also
        do_accounting("db","missed");

        route(relay);
}


route[relay] {
        # for INVITEs enable some additional helper routes
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {

                if (isflagset(NAT)) {
                        rtpengine_offer("ro");
                }

                t_on_branch("per_branch_ops");
                t_on_reply("handle_nat");
                t_on_failure("missed_call");
        }

        if (isflagset(NAT)) {
                add_rr_param(";nat=yes");
        }

        if (!t_relay()) {
                send_reply("500","Internal Error");
        }
        exit;
}


# Presence route
route[handle_presence]
{
        if (!t_newtran()) {
                sl_reply_error();
                exit;
        }

        if(is_method("PUBLISH")) {
                handle_publish();
        } else
        if( is_method("SUBSCRIBE")) {
                handle_subscribe();
        }

        exit;
}


branch_route[per_branch_ops] {
        xlog("new branch at $ru\n");
}


onreply_route[handle_nat] {
        if (nat_uac_test("1"))
                fix_nated_contact();
        if ( isflagset(NAT) )
                rtpengine_answer("ro");
        xlog("incoming reply\n");
}


failure_route[missed_call] {
        if (t_was_cancelled()) {
                exit;
        }

        # uncomment the following lines if you want to block client
        # redirect based on 3xx replies.
        ##if (t_check_status("3[0-9][0-9]")) {
        ##t_reply("404","Not found");
        ##      exit;
        ##}


        # redirect the failed to a different VM system
        if (t_check_status("486|408")) {
                $du = "sip:127.0.0.2:5060"; # CUSTOMIZE ME
                # do not set the missed call flag again
                route(relay);
        }
}



local_route {
        if (is_method("BYE") && $DLG_dir=="UPSTREAM") {

                acc_db_request("200 Dialog Timeout", "acc");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `dialplan` table, you have added extra quotes around the `dialplan.subst_exp` and `dialplan.repl_exp` values.  Instead of `"^089(.+)$"` and `"35389\1"`, try to provision `^089(.+)$` and `35389\1`.  Another mistake is that you are using `match_op == 0` (string match) instead of `match_op == 1` (regex match).  Please read the [dialplan documentation](https://opensips.org/html/docs/modules/2.4.x/dialplan.html#idp2468688) carefully before provisioning data into any of the columns.

The `drouting` part looks good.  It should properly route out the `353` prefix.

Comment: I have done that, but still getting the same behaviour.

Comment: In terminal I am getting "No matching rule for input 0899000000" even I believe regex is correct.

Comment: https://topaz.github.io/paste/#XQAAAQAmAwAAAAAAAAA2nkquIdRDg4Y3FZKAE0RXPFOW6h01f0n6FYUT6opS8Mk0dYK1+u4tJgooYKG5M4DOPlwF9UcNHY5yl5xC3qtHqmZWYJvZFe6BEmlmYtVQgps8D85IL+ldeEWVe0N/BHglj2xgy/cbSEZ5KvKHQmBYEeDy752X993KhSMT/dw72aTUx9wdk6antYwFYWLeZhA/V4i2EIVSuobMZscdTM0BCqb6NC8D6/LwMQGArj4oYhTB94J6XA6HWLou+TZcqnvtK/9jYD5/nmqg7vDeXIsZuL68cy7sDLLC9Vjio+tMb3OsJVsAlfuD4wwruIeBDoJhVPzHzckTbIxb4O/U89b7vjzpFihYKUwd9kNNuADrYwO/wKeFzKqv+rkBsdBX14PEYJJXU8+hcYMI8HbHbLqDYZHT2c+xf5XlZIKxNW7i+K7i7a5C6KoFpEscZhZxU2up8Bomkkv8Sf/y

Comment: Ok, now I understand.  It looks like you are using `match_op = 0`, which is string matching, as opposed to `match_op = 1`, which is regex matching!

Comment: Thank You! Got one step further, opensipscp has to be corrected, when adding dialplan rule from cp 0 is for regeq and 1 is for equal.

Comment: I can see, now call hits dp_translate rule, gets converted to E164 but I don't see any route lookup after checking userloc

Comment: On sngrep I see response to invite "SIP/2.0 420 Bad Extension"

Comment: do `"opensipsctl ul show"` and make sure that exact DID is registered, otherwise the `lookup(DID)` operation will fail!